# Which regression algorithm should I use to predict API call rate (transactions per second)?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am working on an API gateway which handles requests from hundreds of APIs. Some of these APIs have a maximum transaction per second (TPS) of less than 500/day, but during high traffic, the TPS rate can go up to 2k-3k. I want to predict as accurately as possible the expected TPS of the APIs.

I have historical data for the past TPS of all these APIs in a CSV format like (Date, API name, TPS).

We have been doing linear regression on this data, but it doesn't give an accurate prediction of the TPS for each API. What kind of prediction algorithms should I be looking at for this use case? What kind of parameters can I add to this data to make it more useful?

Answer (score 0):

I think linear regression should do the trick for you if you are a beginner. Here are some of the tricks I used to improve efficiency.

1. Vary the learning rate just to be sure.
2. make sure that the hypothesis is convex.
3. Test your efficiency against a test set and not training set.
4. Check overfitting and underfitting (bias and variance)

Linear regression, in general, is not that accurate. I prefer using neural nets with a variety of different activation functions for different layers.
The advantage with neural nets is that if you have features `x1` and `x2`, neural nets will automatically generate a feature `x1*x2` and feed it for processing. This might lead to better performance of the system.

If you want, share the details of the implementation with me.